# Unable to set BoxLayout(JPanel) correctly in GridLayout/FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout

I have a panel with the below code

```
public class PhotoBox extends JPanel {


    private JLabel photoIcon;
    private JLabel photoName;
    private JLabel print;
    private ImageHelper imageHelper;


    public PhotoBox(File file, JLabel print) throws IOException {

        imageHelper = new ImageHelper();
        this.photoIcon =  new JLabel();
        this.photoIcon.setIcon(imageHelper.createThumbnails(file));
        this.photoIcon.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 150));
        this.photoIcon.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        this.photoName = new JLabel();
        photoName.setText((file.getName().length()) > 20 ? file.getName().substring(0,10)+".." : file.getName());
        this.photoName.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);


        this.print = new JLabel();
        this.print.setText(print.getText());
        this.print.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this , BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,150));

        add(this.photoIcon);
        add(this.photoName);
        add(this.print);
    }
}
```

Now I am adding a list of such panel into another JPanel with has GridLayout

```
JPanel tile = new JPanel();
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0,4);
tile.setLayout(layout);
PhotoBox vBox = new PhotoBox(file,filePrints.get(file.getName()));
tile.add(vBox);
```

But what I finally get is something like this

[image: GridLayout Gap error]

I don't understand why is that extra space being taken by all my PhotoBox objects. I want the images to be close together. Not to forget, I have already tried PrefSize() and it doesn't work.

Using WrapLayout/FlowLayout

[image]

Edit :

Now What I feel the problem is with the `BoxLayout` of the `PhotoBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the image's height because the layout is correct AFAICS, there is nothing else. :D

Comment: Thanks, that exactly where the problem was

Answer (score 2):

This is the nature of `GridLayout`.  It takes the available space and divides it equally amongst all the components.  Take a look at [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).

How to fix will come down to eaxctly what you want.  You could use a `GridBagLayout`, but you'll become responsible for supplying the constraints that determine the locations of each component.

You could also take a look at [Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) by Rob Camick.  This is a `FlowLayout` as it probably should have a done, as it provides line wrapping for the components.

You should take a look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more ideas.

You may also consider taking a look at [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: WrapBox helps. But if you see clearly the border has been placed on PhotoBox and it seems to take a lot of space, how can I decrease that ?

Comment: `WrapLayout` is an extension to `FlowLayout`, you can change the `hgap` and `vgap` via the constructor, try passing `0, 0` to it instead

Comment: This is not the problem of WrapLayout. The problem is with the BoxLayout of the Jpanel. My PhotoBox is taking more space than required, pushing the other elements down. I need to know a way to decrease that.

Answer (score 2):

GridLayout is going to fill the available space it is placed in.  So the container that `title` is added to must actually have that height available and Gridlayout is filling it.

Three options exist for a fix:

- Use a different layout manager for your titles
- Use a different layout for the container you are adding it to.
- Put your titles in a new JPanel that has a FlowLayout, then add this "middle man" JPanel to your top container instead of 'title'